# I need help to understand the call back in jQuery mouse events using .call()?

Tags: jquery, events, mouseenter

My main question is what is being passed from the event handlers especially the mouse enter events.

I have code in a plugin as below:

```
(function ($, undefined) {
$.fn.MyPlugin= function (options) {
    var defaults = {
        mpClickCallback: defaultCallback,
        mpEnterCallback: defaultCallback,
        mpExitCallback: defaultCallback
    };
    var settings = $.fn.extend(defaults, options);

    var list= $(this).find("#list");
    var items= $(menuList).find("li");

    var defaultCallback = function (bool, data, element){
    };


    $(list).each(function (){
        $(this).mouseenter(function(e){
            settings.mpEnterCallback.call(true, e, this);
        })
        .mouseleave(function(evt){
            settings.mpExitCallback.call(true, evt, this);
        })
        .click(function(evt){
            settings.mpClickCallback.call(true, evt, this);
        });


    });

    }
})(jQuery);
```

The above code will cause the following handler to fire with the parameters as shown:

```
$("#MyLists").MyPlugin({
    mpEnterCallback(e, el){
        console.log("event data: " + e);
        console.log("element" + el);
});
```

When I omit the first parameter then I get undefined for the el object in the call back.
    settings.mpEnterCallback.call(e, this);

I am trying to provide a simple callback function so that in the HTML script code handlers can be created for elements when the mouse enters or exits.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="MyLists">
  <ul id="mylist-list">
    <li>
      <div class="list-item">My first list item
        <a href="#item1">image link <span>link item</span> </a>
      </div>
      <div class="list-item-footer">
         image here
         image here
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to provide handlers for all of the elements within the plugin as they all serve a function to the page.

Why and how can I determine the parameters for the event handlers.
I see most of the time they have event data for the first parameter, but if I use that nothing works, the only time I can get the event handler's even data is when I use the 3 parameters.

Comment: the defaultCallback was added later in trying to figure this out, I would normally put the function() {handler} in the defaults option array.

Comment: Thank you @jantimon, the article was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the first parameter of `call` is the `thisArg`:

Syntax: `fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])`

Parameters

> thisArg -  The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a
>   function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced
>   with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.
>
> arg1,
>   arg2, ...
>       Arguments for the object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

As you can see in this [short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bHqSR/) the first argument is passed to `this`:

```
function demo(e, el){
  console.log(this, e, el);
}

/* this = "hey"
 * e = "there"
 * el = "!"
 */
demo.call("Hey", "there", "!");
```

Usually jQuery sets `this` to the element so it's probably a good idea to keep this pattern in your jQuery plugin:

```
settings.mpEnterCallback.call(this, e);

function(e){
    console.log("event data: " + e);
    console.log("element" + this);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and I will use this as you described.  I was more interested in why the extra parameter as anytime you use .call() this is implied unless you use a parameter and then it needs to be explicit .call(this, arg)  and thus causing me confusion.

Comment: You are very welcome :) There is also `.apply()` which does almost the same as `.call()`.

Comment: so the `.apply()` is a part of javascript and is used by jquery.  Good to know.